# Representing a $2 \times 2$ matrix as a $1 \times 4$ vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

It seems to me (acording to assingment solutions), that you can write a $2 \times 2$ matrix as a column vector instead. Why can you do that?

I just saw a solution to an assignment involving 
$$A_1=\begin{bmatrix}
1&1\\-1&2
\end{bmatrix}$$
Where the matrix was rewritten as $$A_1=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\-1\\2\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Maybe you mean that a 2 by 2 matrix can be isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^4$ ?

Comment: Why one 'can' do that depends on what you're doing. They, quite simply, are different objects. However, for many purposes, they behave the same. The relevant result is that [same dimensional vector spaces over a given field are isomorphic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_%28vector_space%29#Facts).

Comment: Was the purpose of your assignment to determine what $A_1$ is ?

Comment: The purpose of the assignment was to determine if $A_1, A_2 and A_3$ was linearly independent. The solution puts those matrices together as one column each in a 4x3 matrix, therefore my assumption above.

Comment: Matrix algebra is a very special case of linear algebra. In other words, it imposes some additional structure on $\mathbb R^4$. So the two are definitely different. Their relations can be best understood in a Clifford algebra setup.

Comment: @theva The purpose of the assignment is a very important part of this question, and should be included in this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have $A_1 = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}$, then it is false that $A_1 =  \begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \\ d \end{bmatrix}$.  Those are two different matrices, they are not equal, and if we were to extend the meaning of equality to differently sized matrices, that isn't how it would be done.

But your problem is to determine whether 3 matrices, of size 2 by 2, are linearly independent.  So the first question to ask is, "what does it mean for matrices to be linearly independent" ?

It means that if you sum up scalar multiples of the matrices, you won't get zero.  In other words, there is no such $c$ such that $$\sum_{k=1}^3 c_k A_k = 0$$

Observe that if

$$
\begin{bmatrix} a_1 & b_1 \\ c_1 & d_1 \end{bmatrix}
\quad \text{and} \quad
\begin{bmatrix} a_2 & b_2 \\ c_2 & d_2 \end{bmatrix}
\quad \text{and} \quad
\begin{bmatrix} a_3 & b_3 \\ c_3 & d_3 \end{bmatrix}
$$

are linearly independent, then so are

$$
\begin{bmatrix} a_1 \\ b_1 \\ c_1 \\ d_1 \end{bmatrix}
\quad \text{and} \quad
\begin{bmatrix} a_2 \\ b_2 \\ c_2 \\ d_2 \end{bmatrix}
\quad \text{and} \quad
\begin{bmatrix} a_3 \\ b_3 \\ c_3 \\ d_3 \end{bmatrix}
$$

This does not mean that they are equal.  It just means that the linear independence of the first 3 is equal to the linear independence of the last 3.

Analogously, if I said to you "The sum of $x+1$, $x+2$, and $x+3$ is equal to the sum of $x$, $x$, and $x+6$", that does not mean that $x+1 = x$, $x+2=x$, and $x+3 = x+6$.  Same principle, but using linear indpendence instead of sum.

So your problem becomes one of finding the linear independence of 3 vectors, which is a more familiar problem.

Comment: This is a very nice answer! I understand it in the way that I only have to care about that $a_1,a_2 and a_3$ corresponds to each other, and not the form of the matrix. This since I only care about the linear independence.

Answer (score 1):

As @gitgud said, any two vector spaces of the same dimension are isomorphic. Since $M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R}) \simeq \mathbb{R}^4$, we may write any $2\times 2$ matrix using any basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$ by the change of basis transformation.

In your example, the bases are simply the standard bases of $M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R})$ and $\mathbb{R}^4$, so the change of basis transformation is essentially the identity, but we have to re-write the matrix a little.